# How to observe properties or instance variables with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I would like to monitor the number of tableview cell and once it becomes zero (delete all the rows) my button would be disabled immediately otherwise (insert a new row) it will be enabled.
And I would like to do this with `ReactiveCocoa`.

I'm a newbee with RAC and what I tried is like this:

```
let count = NSNumber(integer: self.records!.count)
    let countSignal: RACSignal = count.rac_willDeallocSignal();
    countSignal.subscribeNext { (AnyObject) in
        NSLog("here i am")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = AnyObject.integerValue > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

But it didn't work.

So far I know how to generate signals and monitor the change with some text fields cause it just comes like this:

```
self.myTextField.rac_textSignal
```

But what if I want to product signals or monitor the change of properties or variables so I could subscribe and pass the signals on and do some callback based on their changes?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a value changed signal by using `rac_valuesForKeyPath` method to observer the property value,here is an tutorials:[SWIFT AND REACTIVECOCOA](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/07/24/mvvm-reactivecocoa-swift.html?utm_source=tuicool&utm_medium=referral),in Objective-C there is macro `RACObserver(target,key path)`

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not to solve my issue here, since I coded  `self.recordSignal = self.RACObserve(self, keyPath: "records")` and get a `RACSignal` instance and then subscribe it with next block: `self.recordSignal!.subscribeNext { (records) in
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = records.count > 0 ? true : false
        }` in `viewDidLoad`, but when I deleted the last row, the button is still enabled.